# Getting the NA coefficients from summary of lm.fit object in R

Tags: r, lm, summary, coefficients

I am estimating many regressions iteratively and recording the coefficient summaries for each estimation. Sometimes, the data isn't good but I want to record the outcome none the less.

When the data is bad, and lm.fit kicks back NA's for some regressor, for some reason, it doesn't show up when calling `coef()` on the `summary()`

When I make the following call (simplified for reproducability)

```
summary(lm(y ~., data=data.frame(y = 1:30, x1 = rep(0, 30), x2 = 1:30*2)))
```

As part of the output I get

```
              Estimate Std. Error    t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) -2.595e-15  5.129e-16 -5.059e+00 2.36e-05 ***
x1                  NA         NA         NA       NA    
x2           5.000e-01  1.445e-17  3.461e+16  < 2e-16 ***
```

However... when I make the call to get the coefficient matrix...

```
summary(lm(y ~., data=data.frame(y = 1:30, x1 = rep(0, 30), x2 = 1:30*2)))$coefficients
```

I obtain

```
                 Estimate   Std. Error       t value     Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept) -2.594535e-15 5.128850e-16 -5.058707e+00 2.362068e-05
x2           5.000000e-01 1.444508e-17  3.461387e+16 0.000000e+00
```

The reality is that I want to have the coefficient with NA's in the output as I am constructing other objects and it's causing issues with not matching dimensions, and mis-alignments.

Obviously, this is a toy example to illustrate the problem. My actual problem is on a much larger scale with many more coefficients, and this issue occurs with different coefficients at different times.